# SQL Server : CONCAT with CASE

Tags: sql-server

I have been playing a lot with this and am failing to get the answers.

Query CASES:

1. If there is EndDate in Table1 and no EndDate in Table 2, then concatenate Table1 SSC + Table1 StartDate + Table1 EndDate
2. If there is no EndDate  on both tables then display Table1 SSC value + Table2 StartDate space value from Table2 Data column

Sample of tables

```
CREATE TABLE temp.dbo.Table1
(
     CID INT,
     PID INT,
     SSC VARCHAR(3),
     StartDate VARCHAR(20),
     EndDate VARCHAR(20), 
     Data VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO temp.dbo.Table1
VALUES
(1001,  1333,   'OP','20011505','19952012','OP2001156519952012'),
(1002,  1245,   'OR','20121005',NULL,'OR20121005'),
(1003,  1116,   'OP','20131215',NULL,'OP20131215'),
(1004,  1234,   'OP','20011505','19952012','OP2001156519952012')    

CREATE TABLE temp.dbo.Table2
(
     CID INT,
     PID INT,
     SSC VARCHAR(3),
     StartDate VARCHAR(20),
     EndDate VARCHAR(20), 
     Data VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO temp.dbo.Table2
VALUES
(1001,  1333,   'OP','20111015',NULL,'OP20111015'),
(1002,  1245,   'OR','20131005',NULL,'OR20131005'),
(1003,  1116,   'OP','20131415',NULL,'OP2013141520131516'),
(1004,  1235,   'OP','20121015',NULL,'OP20121015')
```

My query which I am working on is here

```
SELECT 
    T1.CID,
    T1.PID,
    CASE
       WHEN T1.EndDate IS NOT NULL AND ISNULL(T2.EndDate,'') <>'' 
          THEN CONCAT(T1.SSC, T1.StartDate, T1.EndDate)
       WHEN ISNULL(T1.EndDate,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(T2.EndDate,'') <> '' 
          THEN CONCAT(T1.SSC, T2.StartDate, '  ', T2.Data)
       ELSE NULL 
    END
FROM 
    temp.dbo.TABLE1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN  
    temp.dbo.TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.CID = T2.CID AND T1.PID = T2.PID AND T1.SSC = T2.SSC
```

This screenshot shows sample data:

[image]

Comment: ***WHY*** are you storing your dates as `VARCHAR(20)` ?? This is horribly bad practice - always use the **most appropriate** datatype for your data - and for a date, that's a `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` datatype - but most certainly **NOT** a string based datatype!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, just a small syntax error.

Your first scenario:

```
Query CASES: 1_If there is EndDate in Table1 and no EndDate in Table 2, then concatenate Table1 SSC + Table1 StartDate + Table1 EndDate IF you look at your case statement isnull(t2.enddate,'') should be = '' rather than <> '' 

2_If there is no EndDate on both tables then display Table1 SSC value + Table2 StartDate space value from Table2 Data column

For second case statement it should be (isnull = rather than <> for both of them
```

This query will give your desired output.

```
SELECT T1.CID
,T1.PID
,CASE
    WHEN T1.EndDate IS NOT NULL AND ISNULL(T2.EndDate,'') = '' THEN CONCAT(T1.SSC, T1.StartDate,T1.EndDate)
    WHEN ISNULL(T1.EndDate,'') =  '' AND ISNULL(T2.EndDate,'') =  ''  THEN CONCAT(T1.SSC, T2.StartDate, '  ', T2.Data)
ELSE NULL END as concatedvalues 


FROM temp.dbo.TABLE1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN temp.dbo.TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.CID = T2.CID AND T1.PID = T2.PID AND T1.SSC = T2.SSC


  CID   PID     concatedvalues
1001    1333    OP2001150519952012
1002    1245    OR20131005  OR20131005
1003    1116    OP20131415  OP2013141520131516
1004    1234    OP2001150519952012
```

My suggestion(if there are default dates such as 1900-01-01, SQL server will treat them as Blank('') (as for date field blank('') means 1900-01-01')) in cases where 1900 should be treated as valid dates.  If you just need to compare null fields try to use null or not null condition instead of isnull(date,'')= ''

Comment: Thanks a lot. really appreciate it :D